App crashing android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80001001
When I am trying to record video in my app then the app is crashing
Crash:
android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80001001
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2128)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:2044)
    at ai.instaview.sdk.webrtc.record.FileEncoder.initVideoEncoder(FileEncoder.kt:74)
    at ai.instaview.sdk.webrtc.record.FileEncoder.onFrame(FileEncoder.kt:93)

This is how I am configuring the MediaCodec
val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, videoWidth, videoHeight)
    format.setInteger(
      MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
      MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface,
    )
    format.setLong(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 1_000_000.millis)
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE)
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL)
    try {
      encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE)
      encoder!!.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
      renderThreadHandler.post {
        eglBase = EglBase.create(sharedContext, EglBase.CONFIG_RECORDABLE)
        surface = encoder!!.createInputSurface()
        eglBase?.createSurface(surface)
        eglBase?.makeCurrent()
        drawer = GlRectDrawer()
}

App is crashing on below Android 12

did you try different codecs?

What test devices did you try?
